# How dos this do while syntax work?

Tags: c++, do-while

Surprised to find this compiled!

```
do do do int a=1; while(0); while(0); while(0);
```

Thought it was very weird. Please explain thx

Comment: Why do you assume it shouldn't compile?

Comment: If there only one statement in if's, for, etc. you don't need '{' and '}'

Comment: Doesn't compile on `gcc 4.7.2`. The `int a=1` has a problem without the block braces.

Comment: @lurker, Funny, it [compiles](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/G2eV6kUA9a8DgPwr) on 4.7.3.

Comment: @chris yes, that is odd. If I put the inside braces in around `int a=1`, then it will compile in 4.7.2. Otherwise, it throws an, *expected expression before `int`* error.

Comment: @lurker, That's really strange. It should expect a statement (`{int a = 1;}` isn't an expression either).

Comment: @lurker I tcompiles in 4.6. Maybe you have a bad package :DD

Comment: @chris The site you linked to says `gcc` is selected, but the command line it shows at the bottom uses `g++`. With `g++` it does compile fine. With `gcc` it does not. I think my package works fine.

Comment: @lurker, Oh, now it's all clear. Declarations aren't statements in C. In the link, "gcc" refers to "GCC" rather than the C compiler.

Comment: @lurker Well I am talking about C++! `gcc test.cpp` calls the C++ compiler because GCC isn't just one compiler!

Comment: @user5281594 yes, I know it's not just one compiler. Sorry I didn't see closely your C++ tag.

Answer (score 4):

It's just three nested do-while loops.

```
do
{
    do
    {
        do
        {
            int a=1;
        } 
        while(0);
    } 
    while(0);
} 
while(0);
```